# How can I get the "Render" and "Dimensions" panel

Tags: rendering, export, dimensions, panel

I want to export a video I've edited into an MP4 file. I've watched tutorials on YouTube about how to do it and in all the videos I've seen, they've all had panels for "Render" and "Dimensions" whereas, these panels are the only ones I have:

[image: My available panels]

How do I gain access to the render and dimensions panel?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Switch from game engine to one of the render engines, blender internal or cycles.